# How to create custom view sections?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Suppose i want to allocate some space on the screen for a few rectangles, each responsible for holding some data. I am thinking it'll be a TableView with 3 rows

What would be the object representing the outer shape, the box table will sit in?

```
/-----------\
| some txt  |
| more txt  |
| other txt |
\-----------/

/-----------\
| some txt  |
| more txt  |
| other txt |
\-----------/
```

I suppose i could make it a unclickable UIButton, but putting UITableView inside seems awkward.

How is it done in Stocks application? There is a section on top and a section towards the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different headers per tableView: one for the tableView, and you can have one for each section

Green ist the tableViewHeader, while blue shows sectionHeaders.

[image]

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (headerView == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailContactHeader" owner:self options:nil];
        headerView.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", 
                                                   [contact objectForKey:@"name"],
                                                   [contact objectForKey:@"familyname"]];
        if ([[contact allKeys] containsObject:@"pictureurl"]) {
            headerView.avatarView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[contact objectForKey:@"pictureurl"]];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView: headerView];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[contact allKeys] count]-3;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView       
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    id key = [self.possibleFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [contact objectForKey:key]];
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 44.0;
}

-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel *l = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)] autorelease];
    l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    l.text= @"I am a Section Header";
    return l;
}
```

You will find the code for this App here: [MyContacts](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/MyContacts)

For any `…header…` method there is a corresponding `…footer…` method.

How it is done in the Stock app, I just can guess: I think somehow similar.

To judge if this is the right solution for you, you don't give enough informations. But I think so.